# Why does dig Answer my queries differently?

Tags: dns, bind, dig

I am unable to understand why there is a difference in how dig is Answering my queries in the client. I have configured the Zone file as below in DNS

```
$ORIGIN mail.lab.example.com.
$TTL 0
@     IN      SOA     colombo root.mail.lab.example.com.  (
                                      2003022720 ; Serial
                                      56800      ; Refresh
                                      14400      ; Retry
                                      3600000    ; Expire
                                      2h )    ; Min
@              IN      NS      mail.lab.example.com.
@         IN  A   198.51.100.157

;NAPTR Records
pcr20718          IN      NAPTR   10      34      "s"     "SIP+D2U"       ""      _sip._udp.pcr20718

;SRV Records
_sip._udp.pcr20718  IN  SRV      9       17      15103  pcr20718

;A Records
pcr20718            IN A         10.54.80.7
pcr20718            IN AAAA      fd00:10:6b50:4500::9b

$ORIGIN webmail.mail.lab.example.com.

@        IN      NS      ns1.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns1   IN  A   198.51.100.156
@        IN      NS      ns2.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns2   IN  A   198.51.100.155
@        IN      NS      ns3.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns3   IN  A   198.51.100.154
@        IN      NS      ns4.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns4   IN  A   198.51.100.153
@        IN      NS      ns5.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns5   IN  A   198.51.100.152
@        IN      NS      ns6.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns6   IN  A   198.51.100.151
@        IN      NS      ns7.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns7   IN  A   198.51.100.150
@        IN      NS      ns8.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns8   IN  A   198.51.100.147
@        IN      NS      ns9.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns9   IN  A   198.51.100.146
@        IN      NS      ns10.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns10   IN  A   198.51.100.145
@        IN      NS      ns11.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns11   IN  A   198.51.100.144
@        IN      NS      ns12.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns12   IN  A   198.51.100.143
@        IN      NS      ns13.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns13   IN  A   198.51.100.142
@        IN      NS      ns14.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns14   IN  A   198.51.100.141
@        IN      NS      ns15.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns15   IN  A   198.51.100.140
@        IN      NS      ns16.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns16   IN  A   198.51.100.148
@        IN      NS      ns17.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns17   IN  A   198.51.100.149
@        IN      NS      ns18.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
ns18   IN  A   198.51.100.157
```

When i run dig on the DNS Server, I get the responses correctly

```
colombodns2:/var/lib/named # dig webmail.mail.lab.example.com. NAPTR

; <<>> DiG 9.9.5-rpz2+rl.14038.05-P1 <<>> webmail.mail.lab.example.com. NAPTR
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20175
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 18, ADDITIONAL: 19
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;webmail.mail.lab.example.com.  IN      NAPTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns9.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns18.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns11.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns2.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns4.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns8.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns10.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns17.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns12.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns3.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns6.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns14.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns16.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns15.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns7.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns1.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns5.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns13.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.156
ns2.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.155
ns3.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.154
ns4.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.153
ns5.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.152
ns6.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.151
ns7.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.150
ns8.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.147
ns9.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.146
ns10.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.145
ns11.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.144
ns12.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.143
ns13.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.142
ns14.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.141
ns15.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.140
ns16.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.148
ns17.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.149
ns18.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN A       198.51.100.157

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 127.0.0.1#53(127.0.0.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 17 11:02:49 IST 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 678
```

When I am running from the client, I am unable to see tc (truncation bit) set in my queries. Will Truncation work for NS Queries?

```
dig @203.0.113.1 webmail.mail.lab.example.com. NAPTR +edns=0 +bufsize=512

; <<>> DiG 9.8.2rc1-RedHat-9.8.2-0.62.rc1.el6_9.4 <<>> @203.0.113.1 webmail.mail.lab.example.com. NAPTR +edns=0 +bufsize=512
; (1 server found)
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 20571
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 18, ADDITIONAL: 8
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;webmail.mail.lab.example.com.  IN      NAPTR

;; AUTHORITY SECTION:
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns8.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns12.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns13.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns14.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns1.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns16.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns9.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns3.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns10.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns18.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns5.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns11.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns2.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns6.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns7.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns17.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns15.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.
webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN      NS      ns4.webmail.mail.lab.example.com.

;; ADDITIONAL SECTION:
ns1.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.156
ns2.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.155
ns3.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.154
ns4.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.153
ns5.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.152
ns6.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.151
ns7.webmail.mail.lab.example.com. 0 IN  A       198.51.100.150

;; Query time: 1 msec
;; SERVER: 203.0.113.1#53(203.0.113.1)
;; WHEN: Tue Oct 17 11:40:31 2017
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 502
```

Is this have to do something with my DNS Server that Truncation bit is not able to set? I want to see Trucation bit to be set and doing a fallback on TCP. But that seems to fail

What might I be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response wasn't large enough to be truncated.

TC bit is not set when the *additional* section doesn't fit completely – [RFC 2181](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2181#section-9):

> The TC bit should be set in responses only when an RRSet is required
> as a part of the response, but could not be included in its entirety.
> **The TC bit should not be set merely because some extra information
> could have been included, but there was insufficient room.  This
> includes the results of additional section processing.**  In such cases
> the entire RRSet that will not fit in the response should be omitted,
> and the reply sent as is, with the TC bit clear.  If the recipient of
> the reply needs the omitted data, it can construct a query for that
> data and send that separately.

Besides that, the *dig* client supports EDNS0 and negotiates a much higher packet size – instead of 512 bytes, it can receive up to 4 kB.

Comment: Does this mean for queries like NS/A which are basically referral-responses, TC bit would not be set?

Comment: It would be set if the NS records in "Answer" or maybe "Authority" section are truncated, because that's what was queried. But the A records in "Additional" section are just an optional extra.